# Is there a chatbot framework available?

Tags: java, c++, ruby, chat, bots

I am trying to  create an program similar to [ELIZA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ELIZA).  My preference is to implement this project in a  general language such as ruby, java, C++.
is there some framework (open source would be great) available for any of these languages ?

Comment: What makes those languages 'general'?

Comment: @sje397: you can refer to this definition: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General-purpose_programming_language

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the heart of a chat bot there is a natural language  processor (NLP), the engine implements algorithms that would break a sentence entered by a human (e.g plain English) to a series of token  the computer can process.

while I am  not familiar with a chat bot framework   there are several open source NLP engines you can utilize to implement a chat bot:

for example [Open NLP](http://opennlp.sourceforge.net/)

googling for "natural language  processor"  will point you to other sources

Answer (score 9):

I'm answering an old question here mainly thanks to the renewed interest in chatbots after Facebook's announcement at F8 2016. Here're few platforms that you can use to create chatbots:

- [Pandora Bots](http://www.pandorabots.com/)
- [Api.ai](https://api.ai/)

The above two use natural language processing and advanced AI to create chatbots. You can use the above in conjunction with platforms that allow you to create bots across various messaging platforms. This way you can write your bot logic once and deploy it across different messaging platforms (FB Messenger, Slack, WeChat, Skype etc). To achieve this, you can use:

- [Microsoft Bot Framework](https://dev.botframework.com/)
- [Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/docs/)
- [Gupshup](https://www.gupshup.io/developer/home)

Disclaimer: I work for Gupshup.

Answer (score 1):

To my mind, the most simple way to work on bots actually is to use [gaelyk](http://gaelyk.appspot.com/), a groovy framework to develop applications on top of google app engine.

Indeed, using google app engine, you gain a quite easy to use server environment, complete with high load support.

And gaelyk provides some [very cool](http://gaelyk.appspot.com/tutorial/app-engine-shortcuts#jabber) improvements over [google app engine jabber](http://code.google.com/intl/fr-FR/appengine/articles/using_xmpp.html) handling.

Even better, you replace Java language with Groovy, which is more or less compatible, but with very nice enhancements.

Answer (score 1):

Check this bot framework named [JBuddy Bot Framework](http://www.zionsoftware.com/products/jbuddy/botframework/)

Answer (score 0):

A framework for a chatbot... no. A chatbot is a serious field, requiring teams of computer scientists many years to develop. There is no frame that can help besides the general purpose ones that come with them (the string libraries would be a great place to start).

Comment: thank you  for your response, However I am looking for a framework with modest capabilities,  Eliza itself  was a very simple program by contemporary standards.   today it can be implemented with little effort in  a  specialized language such as Prolog

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of frameworks available for IRC-bots, but not specificly a chat-bot. Ruby has a great resource for quickly finding popular libraries/frameworks [Ruby-toolbox.com](http://ruby-toolbox.com/categories/irc_bots.html)

If you want something that is MVC-based I can recommend Autumn. If you want something a little more lightweight take a look at Isaac or Cinch. I've worked with all libraries before and work as expected.